# Blazor Razor code not binding correctly when trying to post to web api

Tags: html, asp.net, model-view-controller, razor

Having issues figuring out why my data binding for my post fails.

If I hard code the data and post it makes it to my web api fine.

BUT if I try and take the form data and send it - it's empty. and nothing is posted to me web api.

It seems there is an issue with my binding and I can't spot anything

App Build - Microsoft Blazor/razor code

```html
    <h2>Add a new product</h2>
    <form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Id</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" bind="@Id" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Name</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" bind="@Name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Description</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" bind="@Description" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="Add" @onclick="@(async () => await Add())" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
}

  @code {
    private const string APIServer = "https://localhost:44377/api/products";


    private Product[] products;

    private long Id { get; set; } = 0;
    private string Name { get; set; } = "";
    private string Description { get; set; } = "";


    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        products = await Http.GetJsonAsync<Product[]>(APIServer);
    }

    private async Task Add()
    {
        //this will not output to debug window nor will console.writeline(), idk why? 
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2}",Id,Name,Description);

        var newProduct = new Product { Id = Id, Name = Name, Description = Description };
        //Name = string.Empty;
        //Description = string.Empty;
        await Http.PostJsonAsync(APIServer, newProduct);
        products = await Http.GetJsonAsync<Product[]>(APIServer);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This might have something to do with listening to the onChange() method bindings.

I had to add the "@" in front of "bind" when binding all my form elements, to solve the problem.